# Python __getattr__ to create attr if it does not exist and return it

Tags: python, django

A little background: You'll notice my comments describe what I'll go through later. Let's say I have the following object...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys

class ContainerField(object):
    ''' An attribute/object storage device '''
    def __init__(self, field=None, value=None):
        self.m_field = field
        self.m_value = value

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        '''
        What can we do here that runs the .get() command but -only- if the key
        does not exist.
        '''
        # super(ContainerField, self).__getattr__(key)

    def __call__(self):
        return self.get()

    def value(self):
        return self.m_value

    def setValue(self, value):
        self.m_value = value

    def _recurseSetAttr(self, attr, values):
        '''Generate our attributes/objects and store them succinctly.'''
        # Container
        #    \_Container
        #    \_Container
        #         \_Container...
        for field, value in values.items():
            if not hasattr(attr, field):
                setattr(attr,
                        field,
                        # field type is known from model caching
                        ContainerField(value=value, field=field_type(field)))

            fdbf = getattr(attr, field)
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                self._recurseSetAttr(fdbf, value)
            else:
                fdbf.setValue(value)

    def get(self):
        # Create the new object from scratch and proliferate it's
        # attributes recursively. 'values' come in the form of a
        # dictionary that we can then use to setattr().
        # So... Create container, set value, find keys for this
        # and create containers that hold the values of those keys
        # and repeate...
        self._recurseSetAttr(self, attr, values)
```

Now, when generating the objects I can have a dict that looks something like this: `{"myContainer" : { "id" : 2, "foo" : { "id" : 3, "bar" : 1 } }}` that, once created, can be called like this: `myContainer.foo.id.value()`

In the scenario there's the `self.m_field` which tells the application what data type the object really is. This is referencing off of Django models but any python could apply.

All containers will have an `id` (or `pk`) key to them as part of their instantiation. This is mandatory.

---

#### The Rub

Ideally, we fill our the top level attributes and only when the user requests for the attributes that lie underneath it do we construct them based off the `id` value and the `field` type.

So finally, let's say the `myContainer.foo.bar` attribute has a foreign key field type. If we call `myContainer.foo.bar.newkey.value()` the app should understand that the 'newkey' attribute does not exist, query against our django instance, store the `bar` attribute as the now more filled out Container, and return the `newkey` value that's been put to memory.

#### The Python Pitfall

I'd hoped it would be a simple `hasattr()` but Python seems to just use `getattr()` with a default `None` (The recursion is real!). I've also had loads of trouble getting a `try: except:` to work.

As I write this I'm realizing how much more complicated it may be due to the recursive attribute setting relying on `getattr()` and `hasattr()` Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. - Cheers

Comment: You may have read this already, but if not it might help you: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access

Comment: `__getattr__` is only ever called for attributes that don't exist. You don't need to test with `hasattr()` at that point, you already *know* the attribute is not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to answer the first part of the question: how to have `__getattr__` call  `self.get()` only when the attribute is not defined already.  There are two attribute access methods in python classes: `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__`.  The first is called every time an attribute lookup is attempted, the second is called only when the normal attribute lookup system fails (including lookups in superclasses).  Since you're defining `__getattr__`, which is only called when the attribute doesn't already exist, you can simply proxy it to a call to `.get`.  Where you run into recursion issues is if you try to look up another attribute of `self`, that also doesn't yet exist, inside of `__getattr__`.  The way to avoid this is to have a list of keys that require special handling and check if the current attribute requested is one of them.  This typically is only needed when implementing `__getattribute__`.

Note that your `.get` method has a problem:  `attr` and `values` are undefined.  I'd give a slightly more concrete answer for what to put in `__getattr__` if I knew what values for `.get`'s `attr` and `values` want.

Comment: Ah! Right on! This was immensely helpful. All of these answers were actually. Thankfully in my actual app I have a few more conditions to work with when creating the `Containers` so I can understand the difference of who's-who when it comes to calling `get()` vs. the `super()`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using the @property decorator with private internal fields. The idea would be something like:

```
class ContainerField(object):
    def __init__(self, field=None, value=None):
        self._m_field = field
        self._m_value = value

    @property
    def m_field(self):
        if self._m_field is None:
            self._m_field = self.function_to_populate_m_field()
        return self._m_field

    @property
    def m_value(self):
        if self._m_value is None:
            self._m_value = self.function_to_populate_m_value()
        return self._m_value

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 5
        self.b = 6

    def __getattr__(self, key): 
        return 'created a new key: {}'.format(key)


obj = Test()

print(obj.a, obj.b)
print(obj.c)
```

Here, instead of returning `'created a new key...'`, you create a new attribute and return it.